# How to handle memory error in Python while using large dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, pandas-groupby

I am getting memory error while handling large dataset.
Inside a 1st function after all manipulation, I am storing required items in different different dictionary. So in my second function I am utilizing all those dictionary and trying to create a dataframe after some logic. BUt I am getting memory error at this datfame creation step.
Groupby function also getting used which again takes lots of memory.

Comment: You should maybe show some code. How are you using PySpark?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.